# Issue with saving Multi Line Text Column In SharePoint Thru JMS

Tags: xml, jms, ibm-mq

I have a multi line text column(meta data) defined for one of my SharePoint library in MS SharePoint 2010. I need this column to save multiple order numbers for my documents. Another application is sending the documents along with order numbers in an XML file thru JMS which I am receiving in my message Listener & saving them in SharePoint using SOAP message generated by another program. Order numbers are passed with line separator \n in the XML file. But when i save the documents the order numbers are not getting saved in separate lines. They are getting saved in one line only. When i checked the generated SOAP message i don't see a line separator usually  &#10(then ;) in SOAP message.This is happening when i pass the XML thru WebSphere MQ. But when i test the same SOAP message generation program thru a normal Java program, i can see the line separator in SOAP message. So I am kind of confused with what is happening. Can someone please help me?

Answer (score 0):

Where is MQ running. Is it on linux/unix? and your sample java program in windows?
How are you getting the message out of MQ? 
What CCSID is used when putting the message? The same CCSID should be used when getting the message out.  This should preserve and return the message as it is.
By the way new line should not be used to separate order numbers in xml. They should be put in their own elements.

Answer (score 0):

MQ is running on Unix & sample java program is on Windows. Thru JMS message listner i am reading the message out of the MQ. I am using UTF-8 as CCID. Also i am not putting new line in xml, i am embedding them in my order numbers element.